# Escape ascii bell character in python

Tags: python

Can someone help me as to how to escape ascii bell in python?

**Exercise:**

```
test='\n\t\r\a'
print(repr(test))
```

**Expected:**

```
'\n\t\r\a'
```

**Actual:**

```
'\n\t\r\x07'
```

Comment: So what is the problem here? I see your output consists of a representation of the input.

Comment: This ancii bell creating problem in file path. So, I want this be escaped.

Comment: Again, I don't see any problems here. The bell character is escaped.

Comment: @quamrana How would you escape such file path? C:\\foo\\boo\r99\a\\coo.

Comment: C:\\foo\\boo\r99\a\\coo is not a valid path.

Comment: The correct representation is either `'c:\\foo\\boo\\r99\x07\\coo'` or `'c:\\foo\\boo\\r99\a\\coo'`. The two are equivalent; but Python prefers to *display* the first form. Why do you care how they are *printed?* I doubt you actually have a path with a control character in in anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a raw string:

```py
test = r'C:\foo\boo\r99\a\coo'
print(test.encode(), test)
```

Output:

```
b'C:\\foo\\boo\\r99\\a\\coo' C:\foo\boo\r99\a\coo
```